Proving or disproving a statement involving inequalities
Prove or disprove that if $a_{1,1},a_{1,2},a_{2,1},a_{2,2},d_1,d_2>0$ are such that $a_{1,1}a_{2,2}-a_{1,2}a_{2,1}-a_{1,1}d_2-a_{2,2}d_1+d_1d_2>0$, then $d_1+d_2-a_{1,1}-a_{2,2}>0$.
